# Updating Certificate on Jenkins server running on Kubernetes (K3)?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server running on a K3 cluster and its certificate has expired.  I have a new certificate in a PEM file my sys admin gave me.  I have tried creating a new secret, `example-cert-tls-secret-20241103` and updating my ingress to use that secret and restart the deployment, and restart jenkins.  I have tried deleting the old secret and recreating it with the new certificate data.  When I list the secret and check the cert with `openssl x509 -dates ...` I see that secret was updated and I went through all the restarts or reloads I could think of yet when I go to my jenkins server I still get the old cert in my browser :(

And if I execute `$ echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect k3-jenkins.example.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -dates` I get the old dates!

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect k3-jenkins.example.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -dates
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, O = DummyOrg, CN = example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, O = DummyOrg, CN = example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, O = DummyOrg, CN = example.com
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Nov  3 23:59:59 2023 GMT
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, O = DummyOrg, CN = example.com
notAfter=Nov  3 23:59:59 2023 GMT
verify return:1
DONE
notBefore=Oct  4 00:00:00 2022 GMT
notAfter=Nov  3 23:59:59 2023 GMT
```

Please note that, `example.com` is just a stand-in for my actual domain.

Comment: Do you KNOW there is nothing splitting the TLS between your browser and the ingress?